# Reverse words in python using list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, reverse

So I have to create a function who take a list like this:
[d,o,g] --> each caracter has a position 
and the return is the reverse word...
So far I have this:

```
def invertido(x):
    largo= len(x)
    for i in range (0, largo/2):
        x[i] = x[largo -i]
    print x
```

I have the following error: *TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment*

Comment: Convert to a list, then try the same approach

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly using the indexing syntax in Python. Try:

```
word_inverted = word[-1::-1]
```

This syntax means "start at the last letter in `word` (index `-1`), move backwards one letter at a time (the `-1` at the end), and move through all of the letters in the word (the `::` in the middle)"

In general, you can index an array (a string is just an array of characters) with the syntax `array[first:last:step]`, where `first` is the first item that you want, `last` is the first item that you *don't* want (i.e. the last item you get is the item right before `last`) and `step` is how far you want to move for each successive item.

You can also use some shortcuts to just grab all letters from the beginning of the word to `last` with `array[:last:step]`, all letters from `first` to the end with `array[first::step]`, and all letters at some interval `step` with `array[::step]`. Lastly, if you enter a negative value for `step`, then you step backwards through the array.

Comment: Or just `word[::-1]`.